# R Plot estimated conditional probability

Tags: r

I am currently following the Harvard EDX machine learning course but don't get how you plot the estimated conditional probability like shown below

[image]

Right now I have the following code but haven't been able to figure out how the plot is created. It is a 2-outcome classification prediction, where the dark line seperates both outcomes. This is the code I have thus far for the data

```
library(dslabs)
data('mnist_27')
train_rpart <- train(y ~ .,
                 data=mnist_27$train,
                 method="rpart",
                 tuneGrid = data.frame(cp=seq(0,0.1, length=25)))
 confusionMatrix(predict(train_rpart, mnist_27$test), mnist_27$test$y)
```

Comment: The code has nothing to do with the plot. What have you tried to produce a sample plot?

Comment: To be honest I have tried a lot but don't seem to even approach the right solution. I have also searched off the internet with no result...

Comment: There's probably a function somewhere, defined just for that plot. But if you want to get this by hand, you could start by using ``expand.grid(x_1 = seq(0,0.6,by = 0.01), x_2 = seq(0,0.6,by = 0.01))`` and predicting the model outputs. Then ``ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = x_1,y = x_2, colour = predicted_value))`` will get you a somewhat similar plot